# How can we call another view from a view Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, extjs

I am using SpringMVC and extJS for my project. 
In dispather-servlet:

I am mapping (welcome.htm to welcome.java file) and (process.htm to process.java) file. 

welcome.java file return view name hello.jsp In hello.jsp I am using extJS for UI components. in hello.jsp when user click a button I want it to redirect it to process.htm so that process.jsp executes

How can we do that or am I unclear about question. Please let me know

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is what you mean, but this is how you redirect

```
@Controller
public class PGPController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/index.html", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView index(){
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("index");
        return mv;
    }
     @RequestMapping(value="/signin.html",method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public ModelAndView submit){
         ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("signin");
         return mv;
     }
     @RequestMapping(value="/signin.html",method = RequestMethod.POST)
     public ModelAndView submit(){
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("redirect:signin.html"); 
        return mv;
     }
}
```

On the example above all POST requests to signin.html will be redirected to signin.html.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bypass the default view resolution mechanism(DispatcherServlet) you use the [RedirectView](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html), then DispatcherServlet will not use the normal view resolution mechanism(URL to handler,command or whateverelse)

you specify the valid views on the UrlBasedViewResolver or its implemention classes